# How to replace specific parameter in JSON file with KeyValue in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my `JSON` file how do I replace specific parameter value with key value pair combination?

In the below `JSON` I want to replace `document` and `code` values with by referring dict `json` sample.

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "211123",
    "_metadata": {
      "version": {
        "document": "CUS",
        "service": "1"
      },
      "rider": [
        {
          "code": "01"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "211123",
    "_metadata": {
      "version": {
        "document": "POL",
        "service": "1"
      },
      "rider": [
        {
          "code": "02"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Referall JSON:

`document`:

```
{
  "_metadata.version.document.CUS" : "Customer",
  "_metadata.version.document.POL" : "Policy"
}
```

`rider`:

```
{
  "rider.code.01" : "RIDER01",
  "rider.code.02" : "RIDER02"
}
```

Example:

In the first JSON record, `document` has `CUS` value and it should be replaced with `Customer`.

If `code` has `01` as value it should be replaced with `RIDER01`.

Comment: @martineau Any Idea on this. Hope this would be a cakewalk for you...

Comment: You should include some of the work you tried.

Comment: As stated above, you must post your attempts on solving the problem even if it is not working. A good start point for you to read is Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: looks to me as a combination solution of dict and string operations some lookup procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be helpful

```
import json

document = {"_metadata.version.document.CUS" : "Customer","_metadata.version.document.POL" : "Policy" }
jsons = {"rider.code.01" : "RIDER01","rider.code.02" : "RIDER02" }

with open('jsonfile.json','r') as f:
    json_input = json.load(f)

dlist = [x.split('.') for x in document.keys()]
jlist = [['_metadata']+k for k in [x.split('.') for x in jsons.keys()]]

for js in json_input:
    for d in dlist:
        if js['_metadata']['version']['document'] == d[-1]:
            js['_metadata']['version']['document']= document['.'.join(d)]
            break
    for j in jlist:
        if js['_metadata']['rider'][0]['code'] == j[-1]:
            js['_metadata']['rider'][0]['code'] = jsons['.'.join(j[1:])]
            break

with open('output_json.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(json_input, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear but if I got it right, here is what you are looking for:

```py
import json

json_text = '''
[
  {
    "_id": "211123",
    "_metadata": {
      "version": {
        "document": "CUS",
        "service": "1"
      },
      "rider": [
        {
          "code": "01"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "211123",
    "_metadata": {
      "version": {
        "document": "POL",
        "service": "1"
      },
      "rider": [
        {
          "code": "02"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
'''

documents = {
    'CUS': 'Customer',
    'POL': 'Policy'
}

riders = {
    '01': 'RIDER01',
    '02': 'RIDER02'
} 

json_dict = json.loads(json_text)

for _id in json_dict:
    document = _id['_metadata']['version']['document']

    if document in documents:
        _id['_metadata']['version']['document'] = documents[document]

    for i, rider in enumerate(_id['_metadata']['rider']):
        code = rider['code']
        if code in riders:
             rider['code'] = riders[code]

json_text = json.dumps(json_dict)
```

If your `JSON` text is in a file called `file.json`, you can use the following code instead:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path


documents = {
    'CUS': 'Customer',
    'POL': 'Policy'
}

riders = {
    '01': 'RIDER01',
    '02': 'RIDER02'
} 

json_file = Path('file.json')

json_dict = json.loads(json_file.read_text())

for _id in json_dict:
    document = _id['_metadata']['version']['document']

    if document in documents:
        _id['_metadata']['version']['document'] = documents[document]

    for i, rider in enumerate(_id['_metadata']['rider']):
        code = rider['code']
        if code in riders:
             rider['code'] = riders[code]

json_file.write_text(json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4))
```

I hope it helps.